# Error in svd(x, nu = 0) : 0 extent dimensions

Tags: r

I am trying to do PCA on data frame with 5000 columns and 30 rows

```
Sample <- read.table(file.choose(), header=F,sep="\t")
Sample.scaled <- data.frame(apply(Sample,2,scale))
pca.Sample <- prcomp(Sample.scaled,retx=TRUE)`
```

Got the error

```
Error in svd(x, nu = 0) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

sum(is.na(Sample))
[1] 0

sum(is.na(Sample.scaled))
[1] 90
```

Tried to ignore all na values by using the following

```
pca.Sample <- prcomp(na.omit(Sample.scaled),retx=TRUE)
```

Which gives the following error

```
Error in svd(x, nu = 0) : 0 extent dimensions
```

There were reports that na.action requires formula to be given and hence tried the below

```
pca.Sample <- prcomp(~.,center=TRUE,scale=TRUE,Sample, na.action=na.omit)
```

Now getting the following error

```
Error in prcomp.default(x, ...) :
  cannot rescale a constant/zero column to unit variance
```

Think that the problem might be because "One of my data columns is constant.  The variance of a constant is 0, and scaling would then divide by 0, which is impossible."

But not sure on how to tackle this. Any help much appreciated ....

Comment: Try `is.finite(Sample)` instead of `is.na`. Also, you read in as a data.frame, convert to matrix and back to data.frame, are you sure that all your columns in `Sample` are numeric (or that `R` thinks they are). `lapply(Sample, scale)` may work better.

Comment: Also note that `?prcomp` already has a `na.action=` parameter which should be `na.omit` by default.

Comment: @thelatemail : Thanks for formatting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Judging by the fact that `sum(is.na(Sample.scaled))` comes out as `90`, when `sum(is.na(Sample))` was `0`, it looks like you've got three constant columns.

Here's a randomly generated (reproducible) example, which gives the same error messages:

```
Sample <- matrix(rnorm(30 * 5000), 30)
Sample[, c(128, 256, 512)] <- 1

Sample <- data.frame(Sample)
Sample.scaled <- data.frame(apply(Sample, 2, scale))

> sum(is.na(Sample))
[1] 0

> sum(is.na(Sample.scaled))
[1] 90

# constant columns are "scaled" to NA.
> pca.Sample <- prcomp(Sample.scaled,retx=TRUE)
Error in svd(x, nu = 0) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

# 3 entire columns are entirely NA, so na.omit omits every row
> pca.Sample <- prcomp(na.omit(Sample.scaled),retx=TRUE)
Error in svd(x, nu = 0) : 0 extent dimensions

# can't scale the 3 constant columns
> pca.Sample <- prcomp(~.,center=TRUE,scale=TRUE,Sample, na.action=na.omit)
Error in prcomp.default(x, ...) : 
  cannot rescale a constant/zero column to unit variance
```

You could try something like:

```
Sample.scaled.2 <- data.frame(t(na.omit(t(Sample.scaled))))
pca.Sample.2 <- prcomp(Sample.scaled.2, retx=TRUE)
```

i.e. use `na.omit` on the transpose to get rid of the `NA` columns rather than rows.

Comment: How about the case of infinite values?

Comment: Came across this issue, what is the use of `t` in 

`Sample.scaled.2 <- data.frame(t(na.omit(t(Sample.scaled))))`

Comment: `na.omit` removes any row that contains `NA`. Here we want to remove columns, not rows, so we transpose the matrix with `t`, pass it through `na.omit`, and then back through `t` again to get the original orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Negative infinity values can be replaced after a log transform as below.

```
log_features <- log(data_matrix[,1:8])
log_features[is.infinite(log_features)] <- -99999
```